# Difference between 'C-b d' and 'C-b D' in tmux

Tags: window, exit, raspbian, tmux, pane

Currently reading through [this](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/) guide to get a good start on understanding `tmux`. However, I am confused about a particular aspect of `tmux`.In the section **Session Handling**, there seems to be a mention saying that:

> To detach your current session use `C-b d`. You can also use `C-b D` to
>   have tmux give you a choice which of your sessions you want to detach.
>   This will detach your session but will leave you’re doing in that
>   session running in the background.

Now I tried out both options. `C-b d` seems to work perfectly fine but it seems like `C-b D` just gives me an option of one session to dettach (no matter how many sessions are running). In which case, the question arises: What is the point of having a `C-b d` and a  `C-b D`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text you have referenced is wrong!
The author was confused by tmux's session and client. Default prefix+d will detach current tmux **client**, not session! Read tmux man page, there is a section that explains clients and sessions.

If you want to play with it:

- Start two terminal windows
- In the first teminal window: `tmux new-session -s "foo"`
- In the second terminal window: `tmux attach`
- Now you have two tmux (clients), you can in either tmux do: `prefix+D`, tmux will ask you which client you want to detach.